# Nested namespaces and ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, namespaces, using

I have a problem which involes nested namespaces and templated classes. I was also able to create test case which produces the same error as the actual code, but is a bit more readable.

Compiling the following code using VS2012 with the 2010 platform toolset causes an error:

```
namespace A
{
   namespace B
   {
      namespace C1
      {
         struct SMeasResult{};
      }
      namespace C2
      {
         struct SMeasResult{};
      }
   }
}

namespace C1Test
{
   using namespace A::B::C1;

   template<typename T>
   class Fook
   {
   public:

      void Yu()
      {
         SMeasResult Field;
      }
   };
}

namespace C2Test
{
   using namespace A::B::C2;

   template<typename T>
   class Fook
   {
   public:

      void Yu()
      {
         SMeasResult Field;
      }
   };
}

void m(){
   C1Test::Fook<int> yu;
   C2Test::Fook<int> me;

   yu.Yu();
   me.Yu();
}
```

The specific error is as follows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MultiVicomTest (Visual Studio 2010), Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  test.cpp
1>c:\code\test.cpp(27): warning C4101: 'Field' : unreferenced local variable
1>          c:\code\test.cpp(26) : while compiling class template member function 'void C1Test::Fook<T>::Yu(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\code\test.cpp(49) : see reference to class template instantiation 'C1Test::Fook<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>c:\code\test.cpp(43): error C2872: 'SMeasResult' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\code\test.cpp(11) : A::B::C2::SMeasResult'
1>          or       'c:\code\test.cpp(7) : A::B::C1::SMeasResult'
1>          c:\code\test.cpp(42) : while compiling class template member function 'void C2Test::Fook<T>::Yu(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\code\test.cpp(50) : see reference to class template instantiation 'C2Test::Fook<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I do not understand why the symbol 'SMeasResult' would be ambigous to the compiler, as it is used in a separate namespace.
What I could find out so far, is that this problem only appears when the classes are templated classes. The same problem does not appear when the template definition is removed.

Can anybody tell me if I did something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug. Gcc and clang compile this just fine and I can't see why it would be ambiguous, either.

Comment: MSVC has never implemented two-phase lookup for names used in templates as mandated by the language standards since C++98. This bug is most likely a consequence thereof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually looks like a compiler bug to me. When you consider that the `C1Test` version of the function compiled without ambiguity, I suspect that somehow the using namespace within `namespace C1Test` is lingering on even into the `C2Test` namespace.

This is further corroborated by the fact that g++ 4.4 and 4.5 can both compile this code fine.

Comment: Yep, the using is leaked on visual and not in g++. Since I'm not a big fan of this keyword, I don't know what the standards are saying about this.

Comment: Interestingly, reordering the code with namespace `C2Test` before `C1Test` results in the "ambiguity" *still* being reported for `SMeasResult` inside `C2Test`. The fact that the declaration in `C1` appears before `C2` seems to be more important than the ordering of the uses.

Comment: My mistake - it's the order of the template instantiations that's significant, not any of the declarations. The second template to be instantiated gets "blamed" for the error regardless of the declaration order of `C1`, `C2`, `C1Test` or `C2Test`.

Comment: Thank your for testing this on g++. At first I feared this case was not fully specified in the standard, but as it seems, the VS compiler is to blame. Unfortunately, we cannot use another compiler due to legacy code and dependencies on other libraries. I guess we will have to work around this by fully specifying the symbols in those template definitions until the compiler team is able to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
    using A::B::C1::SMeasResult;
and 
    using A::B::C2::SMeasResult;
in your C1Test and C2Test namespaces. This solves the issue.

BTW 
Why do you need so many namespaces? STL is very big, but it uses only 1 namespace - std.

Comment: Boost is big as well and it uses lots of namespaces ;)

Comment: In this specific case, we have a large codebase which contains code pertaining to different kinds of radio technologies. We want to move the corresponding classes into namespaces which resemble the technology they represent, hence the need for many namespaces. Due to integrating many other platforms (.NET, Java) as well, we chose a way similar to them (just think about the huge amount of namespaces in those platforms).