# Nested namespace confusion with VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

I have a problem with quite a simple code with VS 2012. I tested this code on centOS 7, Debian 8, 9, Fedora 25, 26, 27, 28 and Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 18.04 both with the latest GCC and Clang compilers in the official packages, and on VS 2013, VS 2015, VS 2017. It works.

Here is a minimum version of the incriminated code:

## file0.h

```
namespace B {
    enum bar {
        HELLO,
        WORLD
    };
}
```

## file1.h

```
namespace A {
namespace B {
    // Some stuff
}
}
```

## file2.h

```
#include "file0.h"

namespace A {
namespace C {

    template<::B::bar = ::B::HELLO> class foo {
        // Some stuff
    };    
}
}
```

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file0.h"
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main() {
    ::A::C::foo<> myFoo;
    // Some stuff
}
```

This code leads to the following compilation error on VS 2012:

> error C2039: 'bar' : is not a member of 'A::B'

As we are in namespace `::A::C` in file2.h (and therefore in namespace `::A`) and asking for namespace `::B`, it seems that VS 2012 ignores the `::` before `B` and searches in current namespace `::A` first. As it does not find `bar` in `::A::B`, it just throws an error instead of searching in higher-level scopes.

Given the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128979/nested-namespaces-and-ambiguous-symbol) on Stack Overflow, there seem to be a bug in VS 2012 with namespace resolution.

My questions are:

Is there a way to solve this problem without changing the names of namespaces (it is very important to me to keep B in ::B and ::A::B)? Like using an other syntax for namespace usage, or using alias namespaces?

Note: the code for bug reproduction was edited (it actually involves a third file file0.h compared to my original post. My mistake).

Comment: I think you forgot A::B::foo<> instead of foo<>. But that shouldn't change your question. Tested your code on visual studio 2013 and it compiles fine.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue on [godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/lehpC2). There is a little error in your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in `main()`: It must be `A::B::foo<> myFoo;`. With this little fix, I wasn't able to reproduce in MSVC 19 2015. (An older version is unfortunately not available - or I didn't recognize it.)

Comment: odd thing it compiles also fine on visual studio 2008.

Comment: Sorry, you are right I forgot A::B::foo<> in main. I'm editing.

Comment: ERRATUM: my simple reproduction of the bug is actually not the exact one. I'm editing (a third namespace is involved).

Comment: @Scheff indeed in the post I made another mistake including file1.h instead of file0.h. I just edited. Unfortunately this workaround is not possible since all files represented here are in different packages.

Comment: Does the `typedef` workaround help (suggest in P.E. Normands answer)?

Comment: I quite don't understand _Unfortunately this workaround is not possible since all files represented here are in different packages._ Templates must be "visible" at compile time. Without including the dependencies, a template cannot be instanced. (In certain cases, it even cannot be compiled but this might be due to bugs in MSVC. There are a lot of weaknesses in MSVC compiler concerning templates. I recently read a statement that they are working hard to re-write this part of compiler completely though this probably concerns the newest release only.)

Comment: @Scheff What I mean is that here, `file2.h` knows `file0.h` but I can't pass any information of `file1.h` to `file2.h`. However, `file1.h` is necessary for other stuff in the program. This is why this bug is quite weird: a bug happens in `file2.h` related to `file1.h` while the only thing they have in common is to coexist in the whole program, but are not related at all.

Comment: ...and I'm afraid there are certain reasons not to switch at least from VS2012 to VS2013?

Comment: That would solve a lot of problem but our project must be VS 2012-compatible for the moment (but with all the problems brought by VS 2012 we will probably end reconsidering that)

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce this bug on visual 2013 and 2008.
It seems to be a specific problem in 2010 and 2012.

Maybe try a typedef outside the namespace declaration:

```
namespace B {
    enum bar {
        HELLO,
        WORLD
    };
}
typedef ::B::bar my_type;
namespace A {
    namespace B {

        template<my_type= ::B::WORLD> class foo {
        };

    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A::B::foo<> myFoo;
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code to reproduce the error (the original one was actually wrong). However, you can't reproduce the error on VS 2013, it only fails on VS 2012 for me (I have not tried older VS).